# What to use instead of window.onunhandledrejection to handle promise errors in different browsers?

Tags: javascript, logging, promise

I am trying to create logger to handle errors on client and send them to server. What is the best way to handle errors in promises (in .then) ?

I am using this code, which works more or less ok only in CHROME

```
window.onunhandledrejection = function(e) {
    if (e && e.detail && e.detail.reason) {
        this.sendErrorDetails('error', e.detail.reason.message)
    }
}
```

It should be separated logger.js file, which catches all the errors automatically.

Comment: You're correct, it [only works in Chrome](https://caniuse.com/#feat=unhandledrejection) indeed.

Comment: @JessedeBruijne so there is no other way to do you as a  cross browser solution?

Comment: There are other ways but more than likely they would deal with overwriting native methods. Meaning for instance replacing `Promise` with a custom function that would internally use the original native promise and just keep attaching new catch / rejection calls when needed.

Comment: You can use a promise library like bluebird that fires these events.

Comment: I had no idea Firefox doesn't have it yet - I remember they implemented it - we've had it for Node.js and Chrome for 3 years now. I'll see if I can find whomever is in charge and convince them this is important :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks! Any news will be appreciated

Comment: Support for `unhandledrejection` is finally gonna land in Firefox 68 - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1362272#c14.

Answer (score 1):

`unhandledrejection` seems to be the only solution, only [Chrome and Safari has supported it](https://caniuse.com/#search=unhandledrejection) (October 2018).

Alternatively, you could use `axios` instead, with which you can use *response interceptor* as a global error handler, check out:

- [this Github issue on `axios` repo](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/367).
- and [this README section on *Interceptors*](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)

Here's a copy of the code snippet from `axios`'s README for ease of reference:

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    // Do something before request is sent
    return config;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with request error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  }, function (error) {
    // Do something with response error
    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```